# How to get services and characteristics from bluetooth LE device

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, bluetooth

I'm writing desktop app in Windows 8.1, and I need to get services from paired device using BluetoothGATTGetServices function. To make it I need to get handle to the device, that I've done and get handle using CreateFile function. But when I try to get service function return error: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SUPORTED). Does anyone know how to fix it or tell what I'm doing wrong.
My device I'm trying to get services is iPhone 5s.

Here is code example:

```
 HRESULT WinBluetoothDeviceProvider::GetBleHandle(OUT HANDLE* hBluetooth, WinBluetoothDevice* blDev)
{
    GUID bthGuid;
    CLSIDFromString(TEXT(BLE_INTERFACE_GUID), &bthGuid); // BLE_INTERFACE_GUID  this is GUID of my Device Interface GUID
    //#define BLE_INTERFACE_GUID "{00f40965-e89d-4487-9890-87c3abb211f4}"

    HRESULT result = S_OK;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
    HANDLE hBle;

    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&bthGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return E_FAIL;

    devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfData = { 0 };
    devInterfData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    DWORD DataT;
    LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
    DWORD buffersize = 0;


    devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    for (DWORD i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &bthGuid, i, &devInterfData); i++)
    {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        DWORD size = 0;

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &devInterfData, NULL, 0, &size, 0))
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
            {
                result = S_OK;
                break;
            }

            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)LocalAlloc(LPTR, size);
            pInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &devInterfData, pInterfaceDetailData, size, &size, &devInfoData))
            {
                result = E_FAIL;
                break;
            }

            hBle = CreateFile(pInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath, 
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL);

            USHORT serviceBuffActual;
            PBTH_LE_GATT_SERVICE servicesBuff = new _BTH_LE_GATT_SERVICE;
            HRESULT result = S_OK;

            result = BluetoothGATTGetServices(hBle,
                0, NULL, &serviceBuffActual, BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
            // this function always retunr ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

            LocalFree(pInterfaceDetailData);
        }
    }
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://gist.github.com/programmarchy/c9d02e22d58bfab3f8bb#file-gistfile1-cpp-L110-L117, without `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`

```c
            hComm = CreateFile(
                pInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath,
                GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);
```